# how to get the subject of my outlook email to mac clipboard through an applescript?

Tags: applescript

I am new to applescript. I am trying to get the subject of the selected outlook (2011) email with the following applescript.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theMessage to the current messages

    get the subject of theMessage

end tell
```

But I am getting the following error message.

Can’t get subject of {incoming message id 392990 of application "Microsoft Outlook"}

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this does not work is that set theMessage to the current messages returns a list. Notice the { }

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theMessage to first item of (get current messages)
    set theSubject to the subject of theMessage
end tell

set the clipboard to theSubject
```

Answer (score 1):

I am completely new to AppleScript ... and am wanting a script to extract a list of both the the 'subject line' and 'date received' from a specific batch of emails in Outlook 2011.
Is this possible.
The script above works great for extracting the subject line from one highlighted email.
Many thanks
Simon

Comment: Please consider using comments for that kind of messages.